# get custom fields only from a sharepoint list

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone tell me how can I get the custom fields from a sharepoint list? I don't want to get all the fields like hidden, just the custom ones or the ones in the default view.
The end result will be to save the schemaxml for each field in an xml file.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
SPfieldCollection fields = list.DefaultView.ViewFields
foreach(SPField field in fields)
{
....
}
```

Powershell or C# will be very helpful.
Thank you

Comment: a better forum to ask this is `sharepoint.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Think your custom fields would be a difference between fields from your content type and parent content type

Comment: By custom fields do you mean fields other than the OOB field types or do you mean fields that aren't part of the list's/content type's definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties you want to check are **Hidden**, **ReadOnlyField**. If either of these is **TRUE**, it means that this field is a 'system field'.

And then you can check (and filter) remaining fields - Attachments, Title, ... - by it's internal name.

Here is the script that will filter fields:

```
$w = get-spweb http://localhost
$l = $w.Lists["Custom list"]
$l.Fields | ? { $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $_.ReadOnlyField -eq $false -and $_.Title -ne "Attachments" } | select title
```

Comment: Actually that isn't true, a field can be hidden or read only and has no bearing on if it's a custom field.  In practice it might be rare to have a hidden custom field, but certainly not a read-only field.

Comment: You are right, I had this filtering one of my projects and there were little different requirements. I admit this is not right. Maybe it helps somebody else... :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a try later on today and will let you know about the outcome.